# Как подключить скрипт JS по ссылке внутри файла JS

Tags: javascript

На странице `index.html` подключается скрипт `<script src="scriptjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`, меня интересует вопрос как подключить внутри данного скрипта `scriptjs.js` другой скрипт, подгружаемый по ссылке - `<script src="http://jquery.com/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` и чтобы этот скрипт правильно выполнился на странице.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4634644

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Этого можно добиться, вручную манипулируя узлами DOM. Добавьте такие строки в вашем первом сценарии.

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = '/путь/к/подключаемому/сценарию';
document.head.appendChild(s);
```

Учтите, загрузка будет асинхронной. Чтобы отследить момент загрузки, воспользуйтесь событием onLoad новосозданного элемента, значения ему присваивать стоит до вставки на страницу. Внутри происходит [установка нулевого таймера](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26941365/5000805), чтобы гарантировать запуск нашего кода после загрузки вставленного сценария.

```
s.onload = function() {
    // Библиотека загружена, но ещё не инициализирована, её код пока не выполнен,
    // поэтому планируем запуск нашего кода в следующем тике.
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Тут код, опирающийся на использование импортируемой библиотеки
    }, 0);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Иной подход заключается в использовании функции [document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write). Этот вариант гораздо проще, но менее гибок.

```
document.write('<script src="/путь/к/подключаемому/сценарию"></script>');
```

Никакие обработки загрузок не нужны - выполнение этой функции происходит в синхронном режиме. Сразу после можете писать ваш код, который полагается на библиотеку. Но учтите, этот способ замедляет загрузку страницы, кроме того, его можно использовать только в синхронно подключенных сценариях (без атрибута async).